# Get mesh of instanced GeomObject

Tags: c++, 3dsmax, maxscript

How can I get the mesh from an instanced GeomObject?

In maxscript I do:

```
gsphere = createInstance geosphere radius:1 segs:4
gsphere_mesh = gsphere.mesh
```

Here is the first line of the maxscript translated into C++:

```
GeomObject *GSphere = (GeomObject*)ip->CreateInstance(GEOMOBJECT_CLASS_ID, GSPHERE_CLASS_ID);
GSphere->GetParamBlockByID(2)->SetValue(0, 0, 1);
GSphere->GetParamBlockByID(2)->SetValue(1, 0, 4);
```

Now, I need to get the mesh, but I cannot figure out how.  There is no "GetMesh()" or "GetTriMesh()" functions.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the mesh of a node you can use something like this:

```
for (int t = 0; maxscene->NumChildren() > t; t++)
    {
        INode* currNode = maxscene->GetChildNode(t);
        Object* obj;
        ObjectState os = currNode->EvalWorldState(GetCOREInterface()->GetTime());
        obj = os.obj;

        switch (os.obj->SuperClassID())
        {
        case GEOMOBJECT_CLASS_ID:
            TriObject *p_triobj = NULL;
        BOOL fConvertedToTriObject = obj->CanConvertToType(triObjectClassID) && (p_triobj = (TriObject*)obj->ConvertToType(0, triObjectClassID)) != NULL;
            if (!fConvertedToTriObject)
            {
                mprintf(L"Error: Could not triangulate object.);
                return false;
            }
            Mesh *p_trimesh = &p_triobj->mesh;
            int faceCount = p_trimesh->getNumFaces();
            //work with the mesh here.
        }
    }
```